# Jquery change event fired before value is set

Tags: jquery, events, onchange

I got two date inputs where the user sets a start date and a end date. After that i got a label where I load the number of days between the two dates that the user selected.

The two date input got a the same class: "fecha" and I handle the data input and the number of days operation like this:

```
$('.fecha').live("change", function(){

    var fecha1 = $('#E2Del').val();
    var fecha2 = $('#E2Al').val();

    var ini_split = fecha1.split('-');
    var ini_full = ini_split[0]+ini_split[1]+ini_split[2];

    var fin_split = fecha2.split('-');
    var fin_full = fin_split[0]+fin_split[1]+fin_split[2];

    var test = fin_full - ini_full;        
    console.log(test);
  });
```

everyting works good, the problem is that this event is fired when I click on the date input, not after i changed the selected date on each input. So to make this works I need to click on any of the two inputs after i set the values.

Any idea on how to make this event fires after the date input and not when i click on the element ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `live` ? What's your jQuery version ?

Comment: Could you show us the markup you're dealing with, possibly with http://www.fiddle.net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're seeing the old value is that when the `change` event fires, the native consequences (namely, changing the value) haven't occurred yet — in fact you could cancel them with `e.preventDefault()`.

What you would need to do is examine the event itself:

```
e.originalEvent.newValue
```

...will return the value that is being assigned.

Comment: I checked, and the `event` object has no `originalEvent` property.

Comment: This worked at the time it was answered, 2 and a half years ago. The `originalEvent` property still exists AFAICT (using Chrome & [this example](http://jsbin.com/batutu/edit?js,output)) - but it's empty. However I was able to get the value using `this.value`. Strange!